# How to upgrade from vivid? Where is the repository for vivid?

Tags: upgrade, 16.04, 15.04, 15.10, do-release-upgrade

***Edit: This is not a duplicate question.
The vivid folders in http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/ are simply not there.***

I understand that this is not directly supported, but I want to upgrade first to `wily` then to `xenial`.

I ran:

```
$ sudo sed -i -re 's/([a-z]{2}\.)?archive.ubuntu.com|security.ubuntu.com/old-releases.ubuntu.com/g' /etc/apt/sources.list
```

In order to be able to upgrade to wily, but there seems not to be a vivid folder in old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/ though wily is there.

How do I upgrade to wily?
Will vivid appear in old-releases with time?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release) and possible duplicate of [Can I skip over releases when upgrading?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/34430/can-i-skip-over-releases-when-upgrading)

Comment: Maybe I should have asked "where is the vivid archive" or "why are there no vivid folders in http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/dists.

Comment: Am I using the wrong path? I am looking in 
http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists which seems correct according to http://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release but has no vivid folders.

Should I be looking at http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases instead?

Comment: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/ still has the packages for Vivid and Wily. Your switch to http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists seems premature at this point.